# Is it fine to use "than ~~~" in front of comparison words?

Tags: grammaticality

> It is better human relations than structural changes that count more.

In this sentence "than structural changes" is an adverb and I learned that adverb can be almost everywhere in a sentence. people around me say that "It is better human relations that count more than structural changes." is right. but I don't understand why "than structural changes" have to be behind comparison words(count more). thanks for reading

Comment: Putting 'that count more' at the end of the sentence makes it unclear whether you mean that human relations count more, or that structural changes do.

Comment: 'It is better human relations **rather** than structural changes that make a more significant improvement in conditions.'

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a preference to include or exclude 'than' - it completely changes the meaning. Also, your example is **not** making a comparison.

> I want more pizza

This means you have some pizza (or have already finished eating some) and you want some more of what you already have/had.

> I want more *than* pizza

This means you don't want *only* pizza - you want *something else in addition* to the pizza. Some fries, perhaps?

In your example, counting "more structural changes" would mean that some structural changes have been counted but there are still more to count; counting "more than structural changes" means that things other than just structural changes should be counted.

Use of "more than" is used in comparisons, but only when there is a recognisable measure between two things being compared. For example, "I have more money than you". The two things being compared are you and me, but the measure is money.

Comment: "I want more than pizza" usually means that you don't want pizza at all, not that you want something else in addition to it.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is a little awkward. I believe the meaning is:

> better human relations count more than structural changes

which they have worded as

> It is better human relations that count more than structural changes.

You are making a comparison of two things: "better human relations" and "structural changes." The only alternative would be to say:

structural changes count less than better human relations

but that puts the emphasis on "structural changes" when it should be on "better human relations."